# PHP class performance over multiple declarations

Tags: php, performance, class

Let's say I have a huge class named Foo.
if I have to call this class several times in different classes, what is the best way to use it?

Note: *Bar is not the only class that will use Foo.*

Option #1 (create object when its needed):

```
class Bar
{
    public function myMethod($arg)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $something = $foo->doSomething($arg);

        return $something;
    }
}
```

Option #2 (create it once):

```
class Bar
{
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

Option #3 (make Foo static):

```
class Bar
{
    public function myMethod($arg)
    {
        return Foo::doSomething($arg);
    }
}
```

Option #4:

// tell me the proper way to do it

Comment: What do you mean by saying **huge class**? Classes should NOT be huge!

Comment: Inject it as an argument/parameter?

Comment: @bub - _huge_ is subjective. Not to mention relative.

Comment: my class has 10 method and two big array as property: one array contain country list the other one all the php locale and languages. is that huge?

Comment: NO way to answer this. you haven't explained anything of what this class does, or if you can re-use the same instance of it, or need separate instances, yada yada yada

Comment: Please add what fields are in Foo, maybe we could propose a refactoring (other entities in Foo...)

Comment: Im searching how to edit my post. Cant figure it out yet.

Comment: @domal - there's an 'edit' link below the question, on the line underneath the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I'd say is to instantiate `Foo` outside the `Bar` class and inject it as a dependency - the best way to do this would be via constructor:

```
class Bar
{
    private $foo;

    public function __construct(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = foo;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar($foo);
```

Then do the same for all classes that have `Foo` as a dependency. You can reuse the instance if it is suitable or you can create a new one if needed.

Comment: Totally agree to inject, also a good idea for the OP is to break down the class Foo if it is huge

Comment: is property $foo and global $foo two copies of Foo?

Comment: Nope. you instantiate Foo and pass it to the Bar construct, it is passed by reference (same instance)